# What does (Error 32105) mean when I try to sell an item on the auction house?

Tags: diablo-iii

Why can't I create more than 8 auctions at once?

I get an "Itemname auction failed. (Error 32105)" when I attempt to create the ninth auction, am I not supposed to be able to put up to 10 items on the AH for sale?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've gotten that error repeatedly, and it seems tied to particular items, rather than anything to do with the limit on your number of auctions.

The speculation is that items can have less than 1 point of durability loss, which causes them to not show as needing repair, but also prevents them from going up for auction.

I just tried this, and it worked:
sell the item(s) you are getting this error for to an in-game merchant, then buy them back.  Then repair all.

This fixed the two items I was most recently having problems with, and allowed me to put them up for auction.

**Update** [Patch 1.0.2.9950 Release Notes](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/blog/5077622/Patch_102b_Now_Live-07_06_2012)

It is worth noting that as of Diablo 3 patch 1.0.2.9950 this is no longer the case as you're now able to auction items that are not at 100% durability.

From the patch notes:

- Damaged items can now be sold on the auction house
- Once sold, damaged items will be repaired automatically when moved from the purchasing player's Completed tab to their stash
- Please note that unsold damage items will not be automatically repaired when returned to the seller's stash

Answer (score 2):

The AH has been currently under maintenance and experiencing *a lot* of problems.  I would check to make sure you don't have 2 items waiting to be collected (payment or non-sold auctions).  If you still are having problems, I would recommend either waiting for a patch or contacting their customer service.